# what is a best data structure to store tables having K-V columns

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array, data-structures, hashmap

I am using Apache POI to extract tables from word document. These tables have first column of key, second of value and it could be any number of such paired columns. Currently, I am iterating each table, each row, each cell to store all cells sequentially row wise in `List<String>`

Ultimate goal is to store results in `CSV` with 2 columns `Attribute name` and `Attribute value` and `K-V` columns should be iterated in top-bottom fashion and then proceed to next 2 columns if exists.

I am iterating through `List<String>`(`i` being index counter) and using below pseudo code to do so:

- Using booleans `keyB` and `valueB` and initializing `keyB` to `true` and `valueB` to `false`.
- `If(keyB)` then store current string as `Attribute name` and do `i++`. Mark `keyB` to `false` and `valueB` to `true`.
- `if(valueB)` then store current String as `Attribute value` and do `i=i+<NO_OF_COLUMNS> -1` to get to position of key present at next row and mark `keyB` to `true`.
- I am also storing `topKeyInd` which is initialized to first row's key index(0th element of `List`)
- when we are at last row's value cell then I've used condition
  `if(i+<NO_OF_COLUMNS> -1)> List.size())` then we have to start from next pair of K-V columns if exists. So, `i = topKeyInd +2` to get to 3rd column first key cell and update `topKeyInd` accordingly.
- Continue above process until we get to last element of `List`.

It seems to be very complex, is there a better way to handle it?

Comment: could you put the input word file and expected CSV files image in question? `OpenCSV`  might be helpful.

Comment: I can't put any image because of rating less than 10 but it did created image link for me - https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJhl5.png

Comment: Can you add your code ?

Comment: How does it help? That code is working, I am seeking for alternate solution. Also, real code is pretty complicated with some other business scenarios involved. I scooped out pseudo logic that might have possibility of optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ConcurrentHashMap ( ex: ConcurrentHashMap) because is fast and threadsafe :)

for your example :

```
public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> hashMap = new concurrentHashMap<>();

for( int i = 0 ; i< list.size(); i+=2){
    hashMap.put(list.get(i), list.get(i+1));
}
```

[Here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-map-example/) you have some example for simple map.

Comment: This won't solve problem as you are storing results row wise but we need to store K-V pairs for 1st two columns(from top to bottom) and then proceed to next two columns.